# jquery links fade in/out

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, dom

I am trying to get my wordpress internal links to appear in a content div, instead of doing a normal page reload. The fade in/out is working correctly, but the div content is not changing. Firebug is showing no errors, and all internal links are now only adding "#/" to the page link, how would I make sure the link is correctly being added back in with jquery?
Thanks in advance,

P.S, I am following the "css-tricks: ajaxing a wordpress theme" video if that helps,

```
    $(function() {

        $(".home li.home").removeClass("home").addClass("current_page_item");
        var $mainContent = $("#content"),

            URL = '',
            siteURL = "http://" + top.location.host.toString(),
            $internalLinks = $("a[href^='"+siteURL+"']"),
            hash = window.location.hash,
            $el, $allLinks = $("a");

        if (hash) {
            $mainContent.animate({ opacity: "0.1" });
            $(".current_page_item").removeClass("current_page_item");
            $("a[href="+hash+"]").addClass("current_link").parent().addClass("current_page_item");
            hash = hash.substring(1);
            URL = hash + " #content";
            $mainContent.load(URL, function() {
                $mainContent.animate({ opacity: "1" });
            });
        }

        $internalLinks.each(function() {
            $(this).attr("href", "#" + this.pathname);
        }).click(function() {
            $mainContent.animate({ opacity: "0.1" });
            $el = $(this);
            $(".current_page_item").removeClass("current_page_item");
            $allLinks.removeClass("current_link");
            URL = $el.attr("href").substring(1);
            URL = URL + " #content";
            $mainContent.load(URL, function() {
                $el.addClass("current_link").parent().addClass("current_page_item");
                $mainContent.animate({ opacity: "1" });
            });

        });
});
```

Comment: Have you tryed to output `this.pathname`? Because I'm quite sure that it is undefined. Thus explaining why you end up with only '#' as a link.

Comment: That looks right, pathname isnt showing up, should this be included in jquery, or should i use var pathname = window.location.pathname?

Comment: This is not included in jQuery. You should be using `window.location.href`. This will return the adres of the current page.

Comment: In this instance I'm trying to grab the half of the internal links, just using window.location.href alone grabs the whole link to the page the user is currently on, is there a way to use it for other pages, for example grabbing the /about and /contact page perhaps?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your saying but, do you mean if the link would be `http://www.site.com/page`. You only want the `/page` part?

Answer (score 0):

Can you put in `console.log(variableName)` in your method and see if the output of the variable in firebug is what you expect?